# Oracle to postgres bad data move

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I can able to inserted corrupted record directly in postgres.

But while fetching same record from oracle using Oracle_fdw ,I am seeing the following error.I learned from your comments on other blogs,we need to correct source data.Is there anyway we can move data as it is from oracle to postgres.

ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe6 0x96 0xe3

Thanks

Comment: This is not necessarily corrupted data, more likely encoding/locale differences between the two databases. What is the encoding/locale for the Oracle and Postgres databases.

Comment: Here is the scenario: 1) Browser read this special characters data 2)and java code converted this special character hex value to something else 3)wrongly converted record inserted into oracle 4)by using oracle_fdw I am facing this issue,but same record manually i can insert in postgres.  Hope,this help to understand  my issue.Thanks

Comment: Server postgres is:utf8  ,Oracle:AL32UTF8